# Does Python's "\x00" exist in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm currently working on transitioning from Python to Node.js, but I can't figure out if there is an easy way to add a non-printable character to a string.

In Python it would look something like this:

```
conn.send("\x01SomeMoreTextHere")
```

But in Javascript I can't seem to find anything simpler than

```
conn.write(fromCharCode(parseInt("0x01")) + "SomeMoreTextHere")
```

Or if you are fine with using decimals, in this specific case it doesn't matter to me, you can skip the parseInt part.

I can't find any other way that happens to be as simple as the Python way, am I not looking hard enough?

Comment: [Yes, Javascript supports `\xdd` escape sequences](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/escapesequence.shtml).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't know why I didn't try it first... I couldn't find it in the developer resources I checked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes, Javascript supports `\xdd` escape sequences
>   - Martijn Peters

Looks like the answer to me.

[Escape sequences](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/escapesequence.shtml)
Also MDN:
[String literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals)

- hex, octal, unicode...

Comment: I guess I just got proof that W3Schools is best left to rot.

Comment: Yes. Make MDN your go-to place for resources.